# jquery ajax : add form value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery Ajax to post form values.
Is there a way to add values dynamically ?
This code doesn't work:

```
MY_APP_LOGIN.loginFormAttachEvent = function () {
$( "#login" ).unbind('submit').removeAttr('onsubmit').on('submit', function(event) {

        var values = $( this ).serializeArray();
        var o = { foo: 'bar' };
        //o.pageKey = MY_APP_NAV.CMS_PAGE_KEY;
        values.push(o);

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/user/loginajax',
            data : values,
            dataType : "json",
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do this long ago, I quickly dug this up from an old file I did it in. Sorry I can't test it for you now but this should work:

```
var form = $(this);
var form_data = new FormData(form[0]);
form_data.append('foo', 'bar');
form_data.serializeArray();
```

EDIT: I think you can skip the serialize, you can send form_data directly and it should be fine I think.